# Fortran90 output on file error

Tags: file, fortran, output, fortran90

I wrote a f90 code to crop some data from a file, but something funny happened. The code is as following:

```
open(5, file = INPUTFILE, form = 'formatted')
open(6, file = 'w_crop.dat', form = 'formatted')
    do j = 1, nti
        write(*,*) j
        read(5,*) second(j), (w(i,j), i = 1, nxw)
        if (j .ge. 20002 .and. j .le. 44002) then
            write(6,19) (w(i,j), i = 1, nxw)
        end if
    end do
close(5)
close(6)
```

And below link is the figure showing the output. It is the same file opened using notepad(left) and gedit(right). The code is compiled using IVF installed in MS Visual 2012. This is the first time I encounter something weird like this.
[image]

Comment: I recommend you edit your question to include the information in the picture - I'm personally not going to follow a link from a 3-rep user, sorry.

Comment: Also, I suspect the source of the problem is your choice of file handles. Why did you choose `5` and `6`? `6` is typically reserved for standard output, although it depends on the compiler. Try using `15` and `16`.

Comment: @Ross I tried including the picture when posting this question, but it did not work. I suppose I need to be higher rank to post with picture attached in questions. I will try your suggestion and update you again. Thank you!

Comment: Could you show us the format `19`?

Comment: I suspect this is just a difference in the file encoding that the two editors assume.  The File > Open dialog box in notepad lets you specify the encoding of the file, ANSI is probably what you want, but try some of the other options and see whether the file starts to make sense.

Comment: @Ross I tried changing `5` and `6` to `15` and `16`, the problem still persists.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt Sure, `19 format(999f10.6)`, `nit = 60000` and `nxw = 75`. Any clue?

Comment: @IanH There is something weird as I keep trying. Let's say I have two text files named, `a.txt` and `b.txt` which have same numbers of data (i.e. row and column), but the simple program only has problem with `a.txt`. Because I tried with `b.txt`, it works fine (i.e. notepad and gedit can view the file ASCII nicely). I'm sure `a.txt` is exactly the same with b.txt in row and column, just the data is different.

Comment: Sounds to me like an issue with your text editor's default encoding. Can you `diff` the two files `a.txt` and `b.txt` or something similar?

Comment: @Ross After changing to `19  format(999f12.6)`, it solves the problem for all files I need to crop. I'm not quite understand why this solves the problem, because the data values I have in all files are between -10 and 10.